# Difference in the scope of a "for loop"

Tags: java

I am a java beginner and I am working on the loops right now.While working on the "for loops",I have come across this situation where I got different results when the code is executed with and without braces.

Can you explain me the reason behind getting different outputs??

Comment: Can you show us both the codes?

Comment: Surely your problem is because when you're not using braces you have more than one line in the loop

Comment: Without braces it only executes the next line. If there are 2 lines dependent on the condition, only the first would be ran when the condition is true. For the loop the same thing happens. Only the first line is looped.

Comment: a brace glues multiple statements together as a single block.  Back in the C times that was so frequent an error (to forget the braces) that some style guides explicitly made it mandatory to use braces.

Comment: For this and many other reasons; **don't use multi line braceless fors** or multi line braceless anythings http://cafe.elharo.com/blogroll/braceless-if-considered-harmful/

Answer (score 3):

Without the braces, you are only including the *statement* after the `for`.  With braces, you are including everything contained in them (everything in that scope).

Example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    System.out.println("Ten");// Will print "Ten", 10 times.
    System.out.println("Once");// Will print "Once", 1 time.
```

If you include braces, it will print both of them 10 times.

Comment: you should replace _line_ with _statement_ as a second statement in the first line is also not part of the loop.

Comment: @jlordo Ah, yes that's actually a good point.  Will update.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is about the grammar of the language.

[From the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14), the basic syntax for the `for` statement is:

```
for ( ForInit ; Expression ; ForUpdate ) Statement
```

Example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) System.out.println(array[i]);
```

In the example above, naturally, the [`Statement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.5) is `System.out.println(array[i]);`.

### Block statements ( `{ }` )

The thing is, **in Java, a statement can also be a [`block`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.2).** A `block` is started/ended with curly braces (`{...}`) and can contain a sequence of other statements:

```
// this is a statement
int i = 0;
// this is also a statement, a block statement with two other statements inside
{ int j = 0; int x = 1; }

// now, as a block *is* a statement, and it contains a sequence of statements,
// the construction below is also valid
{ int k = 9; { int j = 0; int x = 1; } { int a = 0; } }

// also notice that, if not inside a String, white spaces don't matter, so
// the statement above is the same as
{
    int k = 9;
    { int j = 0;           int x = 1;               }
    {
        int a = 0;
    }
}
```

So if you have:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) Statement1; Statement2;
```

Only the `Statement1` is part of the `for`.

Of course, as `Statement1` can be a block, like `{ stmt1_1; stmt1_2; }`, what would leave your `for` looking like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { stmt1_1; stmt1_2; } Statement2;
```

And as white spaces don't matter, you could write it in a better readable way as:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
   stmt1_1;
   stmt1_2;
}
Statement2;
```

Comment: +1 for pointing out that a `for` statement _always_ repeats just one statement, and that `{ … }` is a single statement.  Many of the other replies suggest that there are two cases here;  i.e., that a `for` statement can repeat a statement or a block, and miss the point that the block is still a _single_ statement (which is built from multiple statements).

Answer (score 1):

- Without braces: Only the **next statement is in** the loop.
- With braces: Everything in within the braces is **in** the loop.

Whitespace in Java code is only for easy reading of code. The compiler completely ignores indentation.

See this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    System.out.println("Hello"); System.out.println("World");
```

will print

```
Hello
Hello
Hello
World
```

The same output would be produced by

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) System.out.println("Hello");
    System.out.println("World");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you have multiple statements in the loop.  With braces these statements get executed once for every iteration of the loop.  Without braces the first statement gets executed for every iteration, and the rest of the statements are executed after the loop has completed.

Without braces:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
System.out.println("Inside for loop");
System.out.println("Outside for loop");
```

With bracesL

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
System.out.println("Inside for loop");
System.out.println("Also inside for loop");
}
```

Comment: _Lines_ don't matter. Relevant are _statements_.

Answer (score 0):

The following examples demonstrate your problem:

This will loop the first line 100 times, but just run the other two as regular prints.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    System.out.println("Test Print 1");
    System.out.println("Test Print 2");
    System.out.println("Test Print 3");
```

This will print all lines 100 times.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    System.out.println("Test Print 1");
    System.out.println("Test Print 2");
    System.out.println("Test Print 3");
}
```